# Creating Remarketing list with tracking code already on website

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to use the Remarketing feature for the first time. I have got the Remarketing code from Adwords and placed it on the website.

Looking through the examples; i have garnered the below flow.

With #2 i can associate one of my Userlist with a predefined Adgroup to be shown during Remarketing. My question is how do i link the tracker ID that i have received (looks like var google_conversion_id = 9925XXXXX) with the code below? where is this linking done? UserListConversionTypes and BasicUserList both have ID's; am i supposed to set any of those or this is done automatically?

Any pointers/help will be appreciated.

Please also let me know if you fine any issue with the code below.

set up remarketing using the AdWords API in two steps:

Create a remarketing list.
 Create a CriterionUserList to tie your list to an AdGroup.

1.Create a remarketing list

Creating a remarketing list involves the creation of two separate entities: the RemarketingList itself and its associated UserListConversionTypes also known as remarketing tags.

The following code shows how to create a remarketing list.

```
    AdWordsServices adWordsServices, AdWordsSession session) throws Exception {
    // Get the UserListService.
    AdwordsUserListServiceInterface userListService =
        adWordsServices.get(session, AdwordsUserListServiceInterface.class);

    // Get the ConversionTrackerService.
    ConversionTrackerServiceInterface conversionTrackerService =
        adWordsServices.get(session, ConversionTrackerServiceInterface.class);

    UserListConversionType conversionType = new UserListConversionType();
    conversionType.setName("Mars cruise customers #" + System.currentTimeMillis());

    // Create remarketing user list.
    RemarketingUserList userList = new RemarketingUserList();
    userList.setName("Mars cruise customers #" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    userList.setDescription("A list of mars cruise customers in the last year");
    userList.setMembershipLifeSpan(365L);
    userList.setConversionTypes(new UserListConversionType[] {conversionType});

    // Create operations.
    UserListOperation operation = new UserListOperation();
    operation.setOperand(userList);
    operation.setOperator(Operator.ADD);

    UserListOperation[] operations = new UserListOperation[] {operation};

    // Add user list.
    userList = userListService.mutate(operations).getValue()[0];
```

2.Tie a remarketing list to an AdGroup

A new type of criteria object called CriterionUserList is now part of v201008. Through this type of criteria you are able to tie a UserList to an AdGroup. As with other types of

criteria, this type is also managed through the AdGroupCriterionService. The following code shows you how to create a CriterionUserList and tie it to an existing AdGroup.

```
    // Create user list criterion.
    CriterionUserList userListCriterion = new CriterionUserList();
    userListCriterion.setUserListId(userListId);

    // Create biddable ad group criterion.
    BiddableAdGroupCriterion biddableCriterion = new BiddableAdGroupCriterion();
    biddableCriterion.setAdGroupId(adGroupId);
    biddableCriterion.setCriterion(userListCriterion);

    // Create operation.
    AdGroupCriterionOperation operation = new AdGroupCriterionOperation();
    operation.setOperand(biddableCriterion);
    operation.setOperator(Operator.ADD);

    AdGroupCriterionOperation[] operations = new AdGroupCriterionOperation[] {operation};

    // Add keywords.
    AdGroupCriterionReturnValue result = adGroupCriterionService.mutate(operations);
```

Thanks,
-Devraj

Answer (score 0):

Those two examples from Google pretty much cover how it's set up

The linking is done behind the scenes by Google - they match the ID in YOUR remarketing tag (which is usually specific to one AdWords account) with your remarketing lists (which are again at account level).

You can have many remarketing lists with varying criteria (visited certain URLs on your site, converted, etc. & combinations thereof) and link one of those lists to your campaign or adgroup.

I'd maybe suggest doing this through the AdWords web user interface first time so you understand the process you are automating with the API

Comment: Thanks Stewart. I think i will try the web interface part to get myself familiar with this. Btw; we have multiple products on my website that we sell;where do i specify the specific page or URL that can be tracked with re-marketing? As per the documentation i should be putting the re-marketing code in all pages; but where can i specific which particular page is the one that should be re-marketed? -Devraj

Comment: When you add a new list it guides you through specifying which URLs should trigger a user being added to the list. Instructions are here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2454064?hl=en but its quite straightforward.

Comment: @user2404330 hoow did you get on with this Devraj? Any sucess?

Comment: @Stewart- Sorry about the delay in responding. I was able to set this up though the UI but the API path is still not clear to me. While setting this up in UI i was specifically asked which URL's from my website i wanted to include (i did not wanted to track all webpages); however, in the API route i do not see where i can enter the URL and how i can track just the user of a particular URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all existing conversion trackers as below.

```
ConversionTracker theConversionTracker = null;

Selector conversionTrackerSelector = new Selector();
conversionTrackerSelector.fields = new string[] { "Id", "Name" };

ConversionTrackerPage conversionTrackerPage = new ConversionTrackerPage();

try
{
    ConversionTrackerService conversionTrackerService = (ConversionTrackerService)adWordsUser.GetService(AdWordsService.v201502.ConversionTrackerService);
    conversionTrackerPage = conversionTrackerService.get(conversionTrackerSelector);
    if (conversionTrackerPage != null && conversionTrackerPage.entries != null && conversionTrackerPage.entries.Length > 0)
    {
        //iterate over conversionTrackerPage.entries and write down the Id of the convertion tracker you need
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Then you can use the Id when creating the conversion type

```
UserListConversionType conversionType = new UserListConversionType();
conversionType.name = "My conversion type name";
conversionType.id = 19XXXXXXXXL; // The Id you wrote down.
```